# Facebook sharing:- "An error occured.Please try again later" when sharing itunes link

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using fb graph api, When I m trying to share my app's itunes link FbWebDialog shows "An error occured.Please try again later".

here is my code:-

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"mayank", @"name",
                           @"test sharing", @"caption",
                           @"example", @"description",
                           @"https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/myApp/id12345", @"link",

                           nil];

// Show the feed dialog
[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                   parameters:params
                                      handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                                        if (error) {
                                         //error
                                        } else {
                                          if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {

                                          } else {
                                            // Handle the publish feed callback
                                            NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];

                                            if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]) {
                                              // User cancelled.


                                            } else {
                                              // User clicked the Share button
                                              NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Posted story, id: %@", [urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]];

                                            }
                                          }
                                        }
                                      }];
```

when I remove or change link parameter, sharing done perfectly.

Comment: If you try with another link, does it work?

Comment: if you try to share second time, will it post??. if that is the case then its bug in facebook.. check this url https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/136768399829531/

Comment: no, not even 2nd time

Comment: Could you share the solution? If another user comes with the same question, he/she'll find the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this for sharing itunes link on FB.
https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=xyz
replace xyz with your itunes app id.